# How can I set the arguments for these parameters?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to build an application that stores input to array,
making the array a temporary database for the inputs **I am only using an online C# compiler dotnetfiddle**

```
using System; 
// Main class
public class Program {

    class Tutorial
    {
    // I used arrays as the property to store the inputs
        int[] age = {};
        string[] name = {};

        public void setMethod(int[] pID, string[] pName)
        {
            age = pID;
            name = pName;
        }

        public String getMethod()
        {
             return name[0];
        }

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tutorial pTutor = new Tutorial();

        //this is the problem
        //I can't set the arguments for the parameters and says
        // I need to convert string to string[]
        **pTutor.setMethod(15, "Hello");**

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, this doesn't compile. `Main` needs to be inside a class. Then: I do not understand what the problem is? Why can't you "set the arguments"? Is there an error? Do you not know how to pass them? ...?

Comment: using System;

public class Program
{
 class Tutorial
 {
  int[] age = {};
  string[] name = {};
  public void setMethod(int[] pID, string[] pName)
  {
   age = pID;
   name = pName;
  }

  public String getMethod()
  {
   return name[0];
  }
  
 }

 public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   Tutorial pTutor = new Tutorial();
   pTutor.setMethod();
   
   
 }
}

Comment: sorry for not clearing that up, it is inside a class Program I thought it is unecessary to include it.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to alter the question.

Comment: When you are calling pTutor.setMethod() you need to pass it the params but putting them in the bracked e.g ptutor.setMethod(1,'aaron') plus take of the '[]' from the method params doesn;t seem like you need it

Comment: when I enter an input like (15, "Hello"); It says I need to convert int to int[] and string to string[]

Comment: Correct, because you specified so: `public void setMethod(int[] pID, string[] pName)`. "15" ist just _one_ individual value, not an array. Same for "Hello".

Comment: I want the values to be stored in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would set them like this:

```
pTutor.setMethod(new []{1}, new []{"Name"});
```

However once created an array is a fixed length and cannot be extended so a list or dictionary (as you have an Id) may be better.

```
class Tutorial
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, string> _data;
    public Tutorial()
    {
        _data = new Dictionary<int, string>;
    }

    public void setMethod(int id, string name)
    {
        _data.Add(id, name);
    }
    public String getMethod()
    {
        return _data[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me! Any suggestion where I can learn arrays in c# more?

Comment: @aaronnim [C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)